# Does one need to dispose of "scratch and sniff" samples before Pesach?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

[This article](https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/seasonal/353/the-kashrus-shabbos-and-pesach-guide-to-cosmetics/) says:

> On Pesach, one may not consume, own or derive benefit from items that
> contain derivatives of the chameishes minei dagan – wheat, barley,
> spelt, oats, and rye. This halacha applies to all such items that are
> fit for human or canine consumption, including perfume and other
> products containing ethyl alcohol. Therefore, one may not use such
> products on Pesach until the source of alcohol is determined.9
>
> According to halacha, if a makeup is unfit for human and canine
> consumption, it may be used on Pesach even if it contains chometz
> ingredients. Nonetheless, many individuals are strict and avoid using
> creams, lotions and liquids that contain chometz. This is especially
> true for lipstick which one may inadvertently swallow.

Some magazines have "scratch and sniff" samples of perfumes. Assume that you know that the sample contains ethyl alcohol. Sometimes, companies will mail people scratch and sniff samples. Does one need to dispose of these before Pesach or is sniffing the perfume sample not considered "usage" or *Hana'ah* as defined by halacha regarding chametz, here?

Of **possible** concern - smelling is a form of *hana'ah*.

Related to this, does one need to be concerned about the entire magazine page (and, perhaps, neighboring pages) having come in contact with the chometz? Or is there only concern with the actual perfume area (the "scratch" area) of the page? For example, if one wanted to read the magazine on Pesach, can he just peel off the scratch sample from the page before Pesach, or is the whole page a problem?

Comment: @ezra - I remember about 36 years ago there being a bottle of acetic acid from Frutarom in our lab clearly stamped "Hametz - not for use on Pesach" (in Hebrew of course), so at least some authorities _do_ regard it as prohibited.

Comment: Related and useful: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%90